# Select Part of Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was wondering if anyone could help with a query to select part of a column.

The column 'criteriadata' contains data that would look like this:

> **CriteriaData**
>
> 14 27 15 C
>
> 14 30 15 DD
>
> 14 38 15 Pass
>
> 14 33 15 Pass

How can I select just the data that appears after the number 15.

Many thanks.

Comment: Will `15` always appear as the 7th and 8th characters? And why isn't this data being stored as four separate columns?

Comment: If you will have many rows you really want to normalize this data. If not, maybe an indexed view with a calculated column would be a work around. Functions in your query (possibly barring aggregation functions) are a good sign it will be slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CriteriaData, 
             LEN(CriteriaData) - CHARINDEX('15', CriteriaData, 1) - 2)
FROM TableName
WHERE CriteriaData LIKE '%15%';
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1aba6/3)

Comment: This assumes that neither of the previous values ever contains 15.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @T table
(
  CriteriaData varchar(20)
)

insert into @T values
('14 27 15 C'),
('14 30 15 DD'),
('14 38 15 Pass'),
('14 33 15 Pass')

select stuff(CriteriaData, 1, 3+charindex(' 15 ', CriteriaData), '')
from @T
```

Result:

```
---------
C
DD
Pass
Pass
```

Comment: +1 for the best answer imo. The question should have been more specific

Comment: @dawsonz it is only insertion of the test data that fails. The query works. This way of inserting the data works from sql server 2008

Comment: Ah yes thank you, having just tested this it does in fact work. Thank you @Mikael

Answer (score 3):

If `CriteriaCData` always contains a pattern of 3 numbers of 2 numerics separated by a space then you always want to retrieve from 10th chars:

```
select SUBSTR(CriteriaCData, 10) from xxx
```

If you are under oracle min 10.g then use REGEXP_SUBSTR to retrieve the alpha pattern

```
SELECT upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CriteriaCData, '[a-zA-Z]*$')) FROM xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want everything from the ninth character onwards, you could use [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
SELECT right([CriteriaData], len([CriteriaData]) - 9)
```

However, you'd be better off normalizing your data so it was already in a seperate column.

Answer (score 1):

On oracle use LENGTH instead of LEN

```
SELECT substr(CriteriaData, 8, LENGTH(CriteriaData) - 9) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT substring(criteriadata, 9, LEN(criteriadata)-8) from table`

This assumes that the position of 15 is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use substring with left functions

Have a look at this: [How to extract this specific substring in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265841/how-to-extract-this-specific-substring-in-sql-server)

And this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259342(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT(CriteriaData, LEN(CriteriaData) - (CHARINDEX('15', CriteriaData, 1) - 2)) 
FROM 
  MyTable;
```

Comment: Though a bit ambiguous, your comment was indeed correct.  I have edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @x nvarchar(100) = '14 30 15 DD';    
Select substring(@x, (select charindex('15',@x,1) + 2) ,len(@x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a SQL function to split the criteria by the spaces and used the last remaining value after the last space.

```
create function dbo.getCriteria
(
    @criteria varchar(500)
) 
returns varchar(500)
begin
    declare @space as int
    select @space=charindex(' ', data) from mydata
    while @space > 0
    begin
        set @criteria=substring(@criteria, @space + 1, len(@criteria))
        select @space=charindex(' ', @criteria)
    end
    return @criteria
end

select dbo.getCriteria(data) from mydata
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had trouble making prior answers work, I had to find my own and figure for future reference I'd leave it on Stack Overflow. My field has XML but it's an NVarchar field and should generalise just fine - if you have a clear criteria for left AND right surrounding strings.

It's not a complete match to this question but I hope it helps someone else who has huge strings in their columns and needs to snip out a string that varies in between two others!

```
WITH r
 AS (
 SELECT TOP 100 RIGHT(XMLData, LEN(XMLData)-CHARINDEX('<INVOICE_NO>', XMLData)-11) AS xmldata
 FROM IncomingPartsInvoiceXML)
 SELECT LEFT(xmldata, CHARINDEX('<\/INVOICE_NO>', XMLData)-1)
 FROM r;
```