# Get all values after certain keyword

Tags: sql

I have some values in SQL table column like this:

```
|---------------|
|    Line ID    |
|---------------|
|ABC 02 TEAM 01A|
|DDF 03 TEAM 3D |
|---------------|
```

What I have to do is, get the values after 'TEAM'

So output should be:

```
01A
3D
```

How do I archive that ?

Comment: Could you post the schema of your table?  It's difficult to determine from what you have posted.

Comment: Select a part of a column:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253445/select-part-of-column

Answer (score 1):

If you really have all that text in a single column, this would work:

```
select SUBSTRING([Line ID],CHARindex('TEAM',[Line ID],1)+LEN('TEAM'),len([Line ID]))
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

```
WITH Lines AS
(
    SELECT 'ABC 02 TEAM 01A' LineID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DDF 03 TEAM 3D' LineID
)
SELECT
    -- Use LTRIM to remove leading space
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(LineID, CHARINDEX('TEAM', LineID) + 4, LEN(LineID)))
FROM Lines
```