# Adding value to column depending on LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SSMS 2008 R2. This is my table

```
PK | DateOf           | Other Columns | Items
01 | 05/30/2017 15:30 | Blah          | truck, elephant, apple, . . .
02 | 04/15/2012 07:07 | Bluh          | foot, orange, horse, . . .
03 | 11/01/2016 10:30 | Wham          | apple, screen, penny, . . .
```

I am trying to search the Items column for each record and count how many times the fruits occur. Conveniently enough, there will only be a single fruit for each record, but it would be cool if the solution would be able to handle several fruits (maybe even duplicates). The result table would look like this for the above

```
Count | Fruit
2     | Apple
1     | Orange
```

I have a complete list of the "fruits". I was trying to figure out how to make it work with LIKE's.

```
SELECT
count(PK) AS [Count]
??? AS [Fruit]
WHERE DateOf >= '2011-01-01 00:00' AND DateOf < '2012-01-01 00:00'
AND Items LIKE '%Apple%' --??(some kind of code that looks for the fruit values??)
```

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing lists of items in a delimited string is not the SQLish way to store data.

Comment: Oh believe me, if I had any control over that I would. It is a sponsored SQL Server hosted on the opposite coast from me for the company I work for. The only access I have is through queries. For some reason they chose to list the items like this

Comment: You can use `CHARINDEX` to find the location of the string then use `SUBSTRING` to pull it out. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265841/how-to-extract-this-specific-substring-in-sql-server. But you'll need a huge inline expression to get it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to store lists.  But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.

In this case, you want a `split()` function.  SQL Server 2016 offers one.  You can also find code for one on the web (Google "SQL Server split string"):

```
SELECT ss.fruit, count(*) AS [Count]
FROM t CROSS APPLY
     string_split(t.items) ss(fruit)
WHERE DateOf >= '2011-01-01' AND DateOf < '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY ss.fruit;
```

Comment: +1 for being stuck with bad design decisions.  And for having about as efficient as possible of a query to deal with the lousy data structure.

Comment: This looks like the route I will have to take. I will have to do some research on string split functions and whatever that "CROSS APPLY" is doing. As an addendum, there is actually another layer of complexity I was unaware of, the "Item" column is actually formatted like so:
    [Fridge] apple, milk, strawberry, [Cabinet] cereal, swiss cake rolls

Comment: @Goatfarmer03 . . . If you want to address the formatting issue, ask *another* question.  This version of your question already has three answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple outer apply to identify fruits if you have table with fruits. Like this:

```
drop table if exists dbo.Details;
drop table if exists dbo.Fruits;

create table dbo.Details (
    PK int not null primary key
    , DateOf datetime2(3)
    , Items varchar(100)
);

create table dbo.Fruits (
    Fruit varchar(100) not null primary key
);

insert into dbo.Details (PK, DateOf, Items)
values (1, '20170530 15:30', 'truck, elephant, apple, . . .')
    , (2, '20120415 07:07', 'foot, orange, horse, . . .')
    , (3, '20161101 10:30', 'apple, screen, penny, orange, . . .')

insert into dbo.Fruits (Fruit)
values ('apple'), ('orange');

select
    d.PK, d.DateOf, d.Items, count(*) as CountOfFruit
from dbo.Details d
    outer apply (
            select
            *
            from dbo.Fruits f
            where d.Items like '%' + f.Fruit + '%'
    ) tf
group by d.PK, d.DateOf, d.Items
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is it requires continuous maintenance of the table of fruits, which may or may not be a problem, depending on what the real data actually looks like.

Comment: Thanks, this may work as well. The list of fruits is set and does not change. Will test this solution out

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

DECLARE @SearchWords nvarchar(max)='Apple,Orange'

DECLARE @Table TABLE (SearchWords nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT @SearchWords

;With cte_Search
AS
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1) )AS Seq, 
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS SearchWords
            FROM (
                SELECT
                     CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(SearchWords, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS SearchWords
                FROM @Table
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY SearchWords.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)

)
SELECT * INTO #Temp  FROM cte_Search


;With CTE (PK , DateOf , OtherColumns , Items)
AS
(
SELECT 01 , '05/30/2017 15:30' ,'Blah', 'truck, elephant, apple'UNION ALL
SELECT 02 , '04/15/2012 07:07' ,'Bluh', 'foot, orange, horse'   UNION ALL
SELECT 03 , '11/01/2016 10:30' ,'Wham', 'apple, screen, penny'
)
SELECT SearchWords AS Fruit,
        MAX(Seq) AS CountOFFruits FROM
(
SELECT C.OtherColumns,
        t.SearchWords,
        C.Items,
        COUNT(C.Items) CntItems,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by t.SearchWords order by  C.OtherColumns ) AS Seq
         FROM CTE c ,#Temp t
WHERE CHARINDEX(t.SearchWords,c.Items) >0
Group by C.OtherColumns,t.SearchWords,C.Items
)dt
Group by SearchWords
```

Result

```
Fruit   CountOFFruits
----------------------
Apple   2
Orange  1
```