# How to get value inside quotes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to separate a fixed expression in SQL in order to get the string value inside `' '`.
For example in the following SQL:

```
declare @value varchar(60)
set @value = 'a.[country] LIKE ''US'''
```

I would like to store separately the information `US`, is there a way to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "to store separately the information US"? You can always take `US` to another variable and concat the string.

Comment: I believe the question is about extracting `US` from `@value` (or whatever text may be between the quotes).

Comment: Conext is missing. Please [edit] your question to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This sample of expression is a fixed expression with multiple possible values (US,DE,FR etc) inside single quotes. I want to parse it in a way, that I could take - the different in some cases - value, that it is inside single quotes.

Comment: @homeostasis please see if this will help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/acc7a1f9-667d-4ae4-80ed-38a20f132592/get-substring-from-a-text-containing-quotes?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
declare @value varchar(60)
set @value = 'a.[country] LIKE ''US'''

select left(Right(@value,3),2)
--OR this
select substring(Right(@value,3), 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure it will fit to your answer but it will give you an idea of using Left, Right and Substring functions in SQL

Answer (score 0):

The question seems incomplete, but based on the question I suggest to use some Delimiter with the dynamic string and use combination of LEFT, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING in SQL to fetch values out of SQL.

**Example**

Following is not the best example, but just explaining how to use it:
e.g

```
declare @value varchar(60)
set @value = 'a.[country] LIKE §''US'''
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@value,
                      CHARINDEX('§', @value) + 1, 100),
                      CHARINDEX('§', @value) - 1)
```

Output

> 'US'

There are already some example about this on StackOverflow.

If you haven't checked out yet other StackOverflow posts, you can refer following:

[How to extract this specific substring in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265841/how-to-extract-this-specific-substring-in-sql-server)