# Using LEFT() and SUBSTRING() to pull only so many characters from string

Tags: sql-server, substring

I'm trying to slice out an exact portion of text from a very long XML field in my database - I only want the text starting at the word "General_Notes" and ending at "General_Notes_Conv" - I used the advice at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265841/how-to-extract-this-specific-substring-in-sql-server) to work this line into my query:

```
LEFT(SUBSTRING(PCO.Cycle_Order_Xml,
                   CHARINDEX('General_Notes', PCO.Cycle_Order_Xml), 500),
                   CHARINDEX('General_Notes_Conv', PCO.Cycle_Order_Xml))
```

Which works, except right now it's pulling 500 characters worth of text starting at "General Notes" - I was under the impression that the second `CHARINDEX` indicates that I'm only pulling text until that word appears - I'm not sure what purpose that second `CHARINDEX` has at all, but I'd like this to be dynamic and only pull from `General Notes` to `General_Notes_Conv` - what should I change?

Comment: The 3rd arg in Substring gives you the length, which specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring works like `SUBSTRING(input_string, start, length)`

Left work like `LEFT ( input_string , number_of_characters )`.

I think for your purpose you just need `SUBSTRING`.

You can find `length` by subtracting  position of 'General_Notes' from position of 'General_Notes_Conv' and adjusting for the length of the beginning tag (which is 'General_Notes') as index gives beginning of a string.

`SUBSTRING(column_name, CHARINDEX('General_Notes', column_name) + LEN('General_Notes'), CHARINDEX('General_Notes_Conv', column_name) - CHARINDEX('General_Notes', column_name))`

Answer (score 1):

`CHARINDEX()` gets you the character position specified. You need to find the difference

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'Some text you don''t care about General_Notes this is the data i want General_Notes_Conv more stuff I don''t care about'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('General_Notes', @String), 
                                      CHARINDEX('General_Notes_Conv', @String) 
                                         - CHARINDEX('General_Notes', @String))))
```

To get only the data between, just a little addition.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'Some text you don''t care about General_Notes this is the data i want General_Notes_Conv more stuff I don''t care about'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('General_Notes', @String) + 13, 
                                      CHARINDEX('General_Notes_Conv', @String) 
                                      - CHARINDEX('General_Notes', @String))))
```

To get both tags included as well:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'Some text you don''t care about <General_Notes> this is the data i want <General_Notes_Conv> more stuff I don''t care about'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('<General_Notes>', @String), 
                                      CHARINDEX('<General_Notes_Conv>', @String) 
                                         - CHARINDEX('<General_Notes>', @String) + 19)))
```